# Right type of custom command to set Info.plist version number based on build type?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm trying to set my application's version number based on the type of build (device/simulator or debug/release) so that I can sift crashes that are reported from developer builds out from crashes that I see on actual builds in the wild.

I'm doing this by using a Post-build Custom Command, which has the problem that it modifies the plist file after the app bundle is signed, resulting in an app that I can't deploy to an actual device.

It seems like if I did this as a Build step instead, it'd avoid that problem, but I fear that it might conflict with the plist merge step that I believe occurs somewhere in there.

Is there any correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a prebuild step to modify the Info.plist in your project, before merging. It's hacky but there probably won't be a better way until we port MonoTouch to the xbuild engine, which is far more extensible - and there's no timeframe for that yet.